# Are there bubble free handheld compasses?

Tags: compasses

We have one question asking where it is [normal for a compass to have bubbles](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15044/is-it-normal-for-a-compass-to-develop-an-air-bubble-at-high-altitude) and another asking [why compasses get bubbles](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/18727/why-do-compasses-develop-bubbles), but we do not have a question clearly asking **if handheld compasses exist that do not get bubbles.**

So are there handheld compasses that do not get bubbles?

Comment: Just a total side note that on boats most of the rather fancy bulkhead mounted compasses get bubbles, especially if they see a lot of sunlight, after a few years. There's compass fluid and a little port to refill them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, there are bubble free compasses. It seems that the trick to getting a compass to not have bubbles is to use a thermo-elastic capsule which flexes with the temperature changes.

> K&R's **thermo-elastic capsule** is flexible, not brittle. This accomplishes two things: 1) the **capsule flexes with temperature and altitude changes to keep out bubbles**, and 2) the capsule doesn't develop leaking hairline cracks when you drop it (or step on it).

[Source](http://www.thecompassstore.com/m1sport.html)

> The Cruiser's instruments are housed in a rugged zinc body with a t**hermo-elastic capsule for durable bubble-free performance,**

[Source](https://www.bestmadeco.com/products/cruiser-compass)

It seems like not many manufactures make these types of handheld compasses, **but they do exist.**