# Can anyone recommend a compass that doesn't develop a bubble at high altitude?

Tags: high-altitude, compasses

I have three compasses and each developed bubbles at 4000m elevation (photo below).

Even the nifty Suunto had a bubble on the first trip. The best was the Silva (on the right of the photo), which developed a bubble only after a few trips to the mountain. These bubbles disappear again at sea level, but I am concerned about accuracy when used at this altitude.

Can anyone recommend a compass that doesn't develop bubbles?

[image: photo of 3 compasses at 4100m elevation that each has a large bubble]

Comment: Good question. [Apparently](https://www.danisch.de/blog/2020/11/29/die-luftblase-im-kompass/) many people think that the bubble needs to be there, but that seems to be wrong. I do remember though that I have read in the manual of my compass that a small bubble that exists under certain pressure conditions is nothing to worry about. Can't find the source for that, though.

Comment: Related: [Compass bubbles: what to do about pesky air pockets in your compass fluid](https://www.advnture.com/features/compass-bubbles). Note that you can get a **digital compass** such as [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Nauticalia-3152-Digital-Barometer-Altimeter/dp/B00DI89GVK) although I am not making an actual recommendation.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you for the pointer to digital compasses. I didn't know they existed. I'll try to read up about their accuracy. I've also found compasses with thermo-elastic capsules, like the Kasper-Richter M1, but these seem to be sold out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it normal for a compass to develop an air bubble at high altitude?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15044/is-it-normal-for-a-compass-to-develop-an-air-bubble-at-high-altitude)

Answer (score 3):

Cammenga makes inductance-damped compasses that don't have liquid, so no bubbles.